# display files copy status before windows 7 get shutdown or logoff with c#

Tags: c#, windows-7, shutdown

I have a challenge, i wonna write a wpf based programm, that copy files from computer to server and it should show the copy status.

To write code to copy files from computer to server is pretty much easy, but the challenge for me is, this copy status application should execute like when i configure a shutdown script on windows 7 in gpedit.msc under windows --> settings --> scripts --> shutdown.

Actually i could do this with a shutdown script too, but the problem is, users do not get any information about copy files to server, and they are asking, why it takes a long until computer going to shutdown. Pretty much all of them do not have patience and force shutdown with pressing the I/O button on computer. So the data copy will be abort during the copy time.

Yesterday i made windows update and observe very interesting things, it stayed, when i went to restart my computer, "Please do not shutdown the computer. Windows update will be installed.". It is possible to show my application, files copy status process like windows update do.

I know wpf provides event SessionEnding, when windows 7 is going to shutdown/logoff, this event is getting fired. But what really disturb me with event SessionEnding is, the message "This program is preventing Windows from shutting down." and explorer.exe is still displayed.

My imagination, how my copy application should work is, it should show only the copy status window, nothings else like windows update do(NO explorer.exe in background). And then after the files are copied, windows will be shutdown.

Comment: Your user's reaction should show you that this is probably not the way to go. How long does the copy typically last?

Comment: It depends, i think it takes 3-4 minutes to copies files, sometimes can be longer. The important thing is, users should know what computer do, not just let them waiting.

Comment: Asking someone to wait 3 or 4 minutes while their computer does something - even if they know what it is - is not a way to get happy users.If I was one, I would just lock the screen and go home, so your program would not get run at all. Or just turn it off, and again your program will not get run.Waiting for Windows Update once a week or month is not a big problem; waiting EVERY DAY is a big problem!

Comment: The user need only some information, what is going on in the background, then they would be satisfied.